# Truncate decimal numbers in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a quick and easy way to truncate a decimal number, say beyond 4 digits, in MATHEMATICA?

With `N[1/6, 4]` it rounds to `=1.6667`.

I want you to cut to `1.6666`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[x_, n_] := N[IntegerPart[x 10^n]/10^n]

f[1/6, 4]
```

> 1.6666

However, note

```
f[N[531/25], 4]
```

> 21.2399

so really some further refinement is required.

Comment: On Wolfram Alpha, I had to use : `N[IntegerPart[1/6 * 10^4]/10^4]` Does your function need an explicit `[x*10^n]` ?

Comment: @Anthony No, in Mathematica it is implied/optional.